# htaccess Disable cache if URL contains string?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, mod-expires

Can I add exception to htaccess if URL contains "string"?
Sth like:

```
<if URL contains "string">
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 days"
</ifModule>
```

?
My caching mod:

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "now plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "now plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "now plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 1 months"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 days"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use `FilesMatch` directive which might work for you. It won't match "string" in QUERY_STRING though.

Also make sure `FilesMatch` directive comes after earlier cache settings.

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "now plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "now plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "now plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 1 months"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 days"
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "string">
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 days"
<<FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I cannot. I run everything through index.php. I need to force one query (eg. with "/stl/"(it's not a path) or "?g=stl") to run without cache. Now I'm using ?token=random_string method :/

Comment: Well that makes thing difficult but still there is a work-around. In that case `?token=random_string` can be internally rewritten to `/link-of-index.php/random?token=random_string` where `link-of-index.php` is just a symbolic link of your `index.php` in filesystem, then write above `FilesMatch` for `link-of-index.php`

Comment: Every solution is quite labourius :( I have about 1000 URLs and about 5% of them have "/stl" in URL => it means 50 symbolic links or do caching manually :/

Comment: No it doesn't mean 50 symbolic links. With the single rule all those URLs can be rewritten to a single symbolic link and then it will be a single FilesMatch section.